# Positioning of legend in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to position a legend of a histogram in js. The part where I'm stuck is  the position of the legend:

[image]

I'm trying to put the legend on right side.

here is the a snap of the code:

```
  var Barchart = function(options){
    this.options = options;
    this.canvas = options.canvas;
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.colors = options.colors;

    this.draw = function(){
        var maxValue = 0;
        for (var categ in this.options.data){
            maxValue = Math.max(maxValue,this.options.data[categ]);
        }
        var canvasActualHeight = this.canvas.height - this.options.padding * 2;
        var canvasActualWidth = this.canvas.width - this.options.padding * 2;

        //drawing the grid lines
        var gridValue = 0;
        while (gridValue <= maxValue){
            var gridY = canvasActualHeight * (1 - gridValue/maxValue) + this.options.padding;
            drawLine(
                this.ctx,
                0,
                gridY,
                this.canvas.width,
                gridY,
                this.options.gridColor
            );

            //writing grid markers
            this.ctx.save();
            this.ctx.fillStyle = this.options.gridColor;
            this.ctx.font = "bold 10px Arial";
            this.ctx.fillText(gridValue, 10,gridY - 2);
            this.ctx.restore();

            gridValue+=this.options.gridScale;
        }

        //drawing the bars
        var barIndex = 0;
        var numberOfBars = Object.keys(this.options.data).length;
        var barSize = (canvasActualWidth)/numberOfBars;

        for (categ in this.options.data){
            var val = this.options.data[categ];
            var barHeight = Math.round( canvasActualHeight * val/maxValue) ;
            drawBar(
                this.ctx,
                this.options.padding + barIndex * barSize,
                this.canvas.height - barHeight - this.options.padding,
                barSize,
                barHeight,
                this.colors[barIndex%this.colors.length]
            );


            //drawing series name
            this.ctx.save();
            this.ctx.textBaseline="bottom";
            this.ctx.textAlign="center";
            this.ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
            this.ctx.font = "bold 14px Arial";
            this.ctx.fillText(this.options.seriesName, this.canvas.width/2,this.canvas.height);
            this.ctx.restore();  
            barIndex++;
        }

          //draw legend
          barIndex = 0;
          var legend = document.querySelector("legend[for='myCanvasBAR']");
          var ul = document.createElement("ul");
          legend.append(ul);
          for (categ in this.options.data){
              var li = document.createElement("li");
              li.style.listStyle = "none";
              li.style.borderLeft = "20px solid "+this.colors[barIndex%this.colors.length];
              li.style.padding = "5px";
              li.textContent = categ;
              ul.append(li);
              barIndex++;
          }

    }
}

var MyBARs = {
    "10%": 10,
    "20%": 31,
    "30%": 70,
    "40%": 50,
    "50%": 30,
    "60%": 20,
    "70%": 14,
    "80%": 17,
    "90%": 155,
    "100%": 100
};
```

Since I'm new to js I just don't get how may I the legend on right side or even below the bars.

Comment: If you could post the html markup, it might help in giving a more precise answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this should work:

```
legend.style.position = "absolute";
legend.style.top = "0px";
legend.style.right = "0px";
```

Adjust the pixels accordingly.